# How to place a map in a tab of a tabbed Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-support-library

What is the best and most standards compliant way to put a map inside a tabbed Android application?

I have intentionally been vague with the programmatic setup of the aforementioned application because I have been wading through compatibility packages and APIs and all manner of sugary Android versions looking for a the most universally compatible method. It seems as though Google wants developers using Fragments as tabs, rather than using the TabActivity setup. Thus, I am forced to use the new Google Maps V2 API because of my necessity for the MapFragment Object. After placing a SupportMapFragment in a FragmentTabHost in a FragmentActivity I am left without a clue as to how to make the MapFragment display something.

I am basically suffering from severe lack of a clue. Doing searching on my own has not been particularly successful because I am wary of using the older versioned Android solutions; I would rather use the Support package, as it seems to ensure that my application will support the old AND new Android versions.

I like sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up converting to and using Fragments with FragmentTabHost in the google support library. The new google maps Android API v2 came out earlier in the month supporting MapFragments, and thus my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way, but I got it working after some trys in this post:
[NullPointer or InflateException when searching on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246085/nullpointer-or-inflateexception-when-searching-on-google-maps/14264460#14264460)
See if it helps giving you an idea how to implement it on your app. I use an actionbar for the tab navigation BTW.