# NullPointer or InflateException when searching on Google Maps

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2, inflate-exception

I'm a beginner and I'm currently trying to get an experiment working with Google Maps Api V2+fragments+actionbar but I think I'm hitting a wall here. The purpouse of this app is very simple, you type a location from either an edittext on a fragment or an edittext from the actionbar, then when you hit search, the app shows the map with a marker on the wanted location. If I type a search and hit the button I get the following error:

```
 01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at alan.android.testMapas.FragOne$1.onClick(FragOne.java:32)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
01-10 17:29:06.560: E/AndroidRuntime(17425):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It only works if the map is already being displayed, but if I change tabs and go back or search again I get an inflate exception:

```
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at alan.android.testMapas.FragSearch.onCreateView(FragSearch.java:35)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f040036, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
01-10 17:32:26.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17681):    ... 18 more
```

Here's the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    public ActionBar bar;
    private EditText txtsearch;




    // private

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bar = getSupportActionBar();
        //mTabSeeker=new TabSeeker(bar);
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Tab tab0 = bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("1")
                .setTabListener(
                        new SherlockTabListener<FragOne>(this, "One",
                                FragOne.class));
        bar.addTab(tab0);

        Tab tab1 = bar
                .newTab()
                .setText("2")
                .setTabListener(
                        new SherlockTabListener<FragSearch>(this, "Search",
                                FragSearch.class));
        bar.addTab(tab1);


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, (Menu)menu);

        View v = (View)menu.findItem(R.id.searchoption).getActionView();

        txtsearch = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);

        txtsearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragSearch fs;
                bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

                fs = (FragSearch) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Search");
                fs.locateSearch(txtsearch.getText().toString());

                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

The search Fragment

```
public class FragSearch extends SherlockFragment{

    private CameraUpdate camUpd1;
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragsearch,container,false);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        return view;
    }

    public void locateSearch(String text){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address>list= geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 1);
            if(list!=null){
            Double lat=(Double) list.get(0).getLatitude();
            Double lng=(Double)list.get(0).getLongitude();
            LatLng ubicacion = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            CameraPosition camUpd1=new CameraPosition.Builder().target(ubicacion).zoom(16).build();
            CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camUpd1);
            map.clear();

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat,lng)).title(text));

            map.animateCamera(camUpd3);
            }else{

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Search Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

FragOne.java

```
    public class FragOne extends SherlockFragment {
    private EditText et;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragone, container, false);

        et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragSearch fb;
                String text;
                text = et.getText().toString();
                fb = (FragSearch) getSherlockActivity()
                        .getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag("Search");
                fb.locateSearch(text);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

fragsearch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        style="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dialog"
        android:id="@+id/txt_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.67"

        android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you all in advance! If need me to post anything from the project just let me know.

**Edit:** I've updated both logs, I think the nullpointer is given because it has to be instanciated before accessing the locateSearch method, so I think I'll have to find a way to pass the text as an argument and located once it has been instanciated, but as for the InflateExceptioin it looks like I'm gonna have to find another way to inflate that fragment's view since that TabListener is the one I use on other apps with no issues regarding regular fragments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the IllegalArgumentException out of the way. After doing some research I ended up changing a bit my OnCreateView() and extending SupportMapFragment instead of SherlockFragment. Here's the code:

```
public class FragSearch extends SupportMapFragment {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        map = getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        return view;
    }

    public void locateSearch(String text) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(text, 1);
            if (list != null) {
                Double lat = (Double) list.get(0).getLatitude();
                Double lng = (Double) list.get(0).getLongitude();
                LatLng ubicacion = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                CameraPosition camUpd1 = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(ubicacion).zoom(16).build();
                CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(camUpd1);
                map.clear();

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(text));

                map.animateCamera(camUpd3);
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As for the NPE, it seems that it was throwing that exception because I was trying to access methods before that object is instantiated so it seems that I'll have to try to find a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at alan.android.testMapas.FragOne$1.onClick(FragOne.java:32)
```

**For your first set of errors,** you have a null value in your Button's OnClickListener. I am guessing that it is `fb` since I don't see where you give any Fragment the tag `"Prestamo"`. But start with line 32 as the LogCat states.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f040036, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

**The second set of errors,** happens because you are creating a new copy of the existing Fragment each time you click on a tab. (Hence the duplicate id error.) Your TabListener should reload the Fragments that already exist. Here is a simple [tutorial](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) to help.

Comment: Thank you for answering Sam! As for the fragment tag, it seems that I was in such a hurry that I forgot to patch that tag but that doesn't fix it either, in anycase, I'll try to add a log with the error from the actionbar edittext instead. BTW, thanks for the tutorial!

Comment: Ok, I've edited the OP with the corrected logs and classes, the illegalargument only happens when loading the tab with the map and has to inflate fragsearch.xml for a second time.